# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Tuple2._1$mcI$sp()I

Tags: producer

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("zk.connect", "localhost:2181");

props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");

ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

Producer producer = new Producer(config);

ProducerData data = new ProducerData("test-topic", "test-message");

producer.send(data);

i am trying to execute this code then got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Tuple2._1$mcI$sp()I this exception.
i added all scala related jar file.plese suggedt me ??????

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Check your classpath to see if sbt-launch.jar is preceding scala-library.jar. Both of them have the same class; scala.Tuple2 from scala-library is the correct one.

After placing scala-library.jar higher in the classpath solved the issue.

Thanks,

Hussain